Adapt python import based on C code structure (file paths) when generated by SWIG
I am currently generating a python module from C++ code using SWIG. I succeed in my goal but the import mechanism is not exactly what I want. I explain with a little example. If my C code is structured as :
/Element
 /BigElement
  /Element1.cpp
  /Element1.h
 /LittleElement
  /Element2.cpp
  /Elmeent2.h

In Element1.h I have a class named element1.
In Element2.h I have a class named element2.
Currently, If I build my python module, both element1 and element2 classes are available by doing something like (all is at root level)
from mymodule import element1

Is there a way to say to SWIG to keep the import format based on the structure of my C code, then I could import my element1 by doing something like
from mymodule.Element.BigElement.Element1 import element1

The accuracy of the example is not important, I just want to know I there is a way to do something like that ? Maybe Using aliases in the interface file or an option of SWIG ?
Thanks in advance
